# Firebase App Distribution With Fastlane issue

Tags: android, fastlane, firebase-app-distribution

When I run the following lane of Fastlane to distribute my android application with Firebase:

```rb
firebase_app_distribution(
    app: ENV["FIREBASE_APP_ID"],
    apk_path: apk_path,
    release_notes: "#{release_note}",
    groups_file: "fastlane/groups.txt",
    service_credentials_file: ENV["FIREBASE_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS"]
)
```

It returns the following error:

```
-----------------------------
[17:08:45]: --- Step: default_platform ---
[17:08:45]: ------------------------------
[17:08:45]: Driving the lane 'android beta' 
[17:08:45]: ---------------------------------------
[17:08:45]: --- Step: firebase_app_distribution ---
[17:08:45]: ---------------------------------------
[17:08:45]: Warning: Debug logging enabled. Output may include sensitive information.
[17:08:45]:  Authenticating with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable: /Users/mbk-ci/workspace/android/attijarimobile_v6/fastlane/attijari-mobile-recette-firebase-adminsdk-k6sfe-5726eeea55.json
[17:08:46]: ⌛ Uploading the APK.
D, [2023-11-07T17:08:46.182649 #32010] DEBUG -- request: POST https://firebaseappdistribution.googleapis.com/upload/v1/projects/812755381591/apps/1:812755381591:android:874285db0d139cc4/releases:upload
+------------------+--------------+
|          Lane Context           |
+------------------+--------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | android      |
| PLATFORM_NAME    | android      |
| LANE_NAME        | android beta |
+------------------+--------------+
[17:08:46]: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

I need to bypass SSL verification to upload the APK, but I haven't found the lane parameters to do that.